# How do I do referential integrity in SQL Server with a compound key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the SQL seen at bottom, why does it return:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'pricedex.table_a' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_delete_from_parent'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE table_a 
(
    [column_1] [int] NULL,
    [column_2] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table_b 
(
    [column_1] [int] NULL,
    [column_2] [int] NULL
)

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_app ON table_a (column_1, column_2)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_app ON table_b (column_1, column_2)
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE table_b WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_delete_from_parent 
    FOREIGN KEY (column_1, column_2) REFERENCES table_a (column_1, column_2) 
       ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Comment: Your tables don't have a primary key. You created a nonclustered index but that is NOT the same thing as a primary key. Add a primary key to your table for column_1, column_2 and it will work.

Comment: I know the same will work if I create a unique index (but not create any primary keys). What "type" of indexes are primary keys and unique indexes that they have different behaviors than indexes?

Comment: SQL Server cannot create primary keys on nullable fields.  Replacing NULL with NOT NULL in the column definitions will help.

Comment: @DeveloperWebs not sure what you mean. A primary key is not a type of index. By default it will be a clustered index if there is not one already on the table, in that case it would be a nonclustered index. A unique index just indicates that the index prevents duplicate values.

Comment: @SeanLange A PK is a type of index and a PK will not accept null.

Comment: @Frisbee a primary key is NOT an index. It is a constraint that does not allow null. An index will be automatically created in sql server for a column with the primary key constraint. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Symantics.  OK an index is always created.  Read your prior comment  "it will be"  - not "it will create"

Comment: @Frisbee lol yeah my verbiage was pretty awful for sure. Should have read "it will create" instead of "it will be".

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `PRIMARY KEY` to `table_a` and change column of PK to `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    [column_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [column_2] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(column_1, column_2)            -- compound primary key
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    [column_pk] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    -- you probably want different pk
    [column_1] [int] NULL,
    [column_2] [int] NULL
);

-- adding foreign key constraint
ALTER TABLE table_b WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_delete_from_parent FOREIGN KEY (column_1, column_2)
REFERENCES table_a (column_1, column_2) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5bfb)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

[`Create Foreign Key Relationships`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx):

> A foreign key constraint does not have to be linked only to a primary
>   key constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a **UNIQUE constraint in another table**.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    [column_1] [int] NOT NULL,           -- with UNIQUE column can be nullable
    [column_2] [int] NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(column_1, column_2)
    -- anyway this table should have PK
);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/734103/1/0)**</kbd>

Be aware that if columns are nullable and you have `NULL` values `ON DELETE CASCADE` will not delete records from corresponding table.

Comment: Well, a primary key OR a unique index.

I guess what is required is an index that forces a unique value.

Comment: @DeveloperWebs A unique can be null but it still has to be unique - you could not have multiple null, null